# Python3 split character list into words from a template

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having some problems after mixed language text segmentation, really not sure how to go about doing this.

```
"template": '新闻 Wang will arrange soon. 在电视'
Segmentation Output: '新闻 W a n g w i l l a r r a n g e s o o n. 在 电视'
```

The desired output is:

```
新闻 Wang will arrange soon. 在 电视
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? Are you doing the segmentation, or does the data arrive like that?

Comment: Segmentation is done and has the output as I wrote it. The question is how to join up the english characters together into words like in the original sentence ("template")

Comment: You have to get the length of the words in the template, and join the characters in the output according to the length. And then add a space in-between words. But that means you will have to know what you want it to turn into, and if you already have that - it seems like something that could be avoided altogether. It would be easier to just output the template instead. Please add some context and code.